# valueBox Shiny Dashboard: custom formatting

Tags: html, css, r, shinydashboard

I am working on a Shiny dashboard and using valueBoxes to display current KPI's. What I am noticing though, is depending on how long some of the text is, it elongates the box to fit the text which then screws up the look.

How do I make it so the text is always only on it's 1 line (i.e. change the font to be the width of the box) no matter what the screen size is?

Also, if you have any HTML or CSS pointers to make the information in a better layout, let me know.

I have to display:

- value
- description of what the value represents
- estimation of future
  value

In my actual dashboard:

- I have the box background color changed
- rounded out the edges
- Have the value font color change based on thresholds

Code:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic boxes"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      valueBoxOutput("vbox", width = 2),
      valueBoxOutput("vbox2", width = 2),
      valueBoxOutput("vbox3", width = 2),
      valueBoxOutput("vbox4", width = 2),
      valueBoxOutput("vbox5", width = 2),
      valueBoxOutput("vbox6", width = 2)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$vbox <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      "55%",
      HTML(paste("test_value that is super long like this",br(),"Estimated: 98%")),
      icon = icon("credit-card")
    )
  })
  output$vbox2 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      "70%",
      HTML(paste("this one is just as long, maybe even longer",br(),"Estimated: 100%")),
      icon = icon("credit-card")
    )
  })
  output$vbox3 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      "80%",
      HTML(paste("this one is short",br(),"Estimated: 50%")),
      icon = icon("credit-card")
    )
  })
  output$vbox4 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      "100%",
      HTML(paste("medium length like here",br(),"Estimated: 95%")),
      icon = icon("credit-card")
    )
  })
  output$vbox5 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      "90%",
      HTML(paste("test_value that is super long like this",br(),"Estimated: 80%")),
      icon = icon("credit-card")
    )
  })
  output$vbox6 <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      "40%",
      HTML(paste("test_value that is super long like this",br(),"Estimated: 70%")),
      icon = icon("credit-card")
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```